# How to retrieve blog post from search page, after searching for keywords in blog post?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i am facing a problem on search page, after successfully searching for keyword in data base it gives me the results but when I click on that result on that search page it doesn't direct me to the original post, let me show me what i mean if someone can help me with this;

```
I need this >>> /blog/blogpost/my_article

Instead i am redirected to this >>>/blog/search/blogpost/my_article
```

## Using Django/ Python, My Search function in Views:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET['search']
    myposts = Blogpost.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    context = {'myposts': myposts}
    return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)
```

## Url Path:

```
path("search/", views.search, name="search")
```

{ # Its an APP inside a Project}

Kindly let me know if you got it what i am saying, thanks

Comment: How do you construct urls to *link* to that post.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem  in `urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="BlogHome"),
    path("blogpost/<str:slug>", views.blogpost, name="blogpost"),
    path("contact/", views.contact, name="contact"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search")
]`

Comment: that is not how you construct the urls in the template. How do you generate the link in the template...

Comment: I need a logic where i can return  back to >> `/blog/blogpost/my_article'  from >>  `/blog/search/blogpost/my_article`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  It is `<form method='GET' action="/blog/search/" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search"
          id="search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>`

Comment: it works for searching purpose but when i click on post in that filter mode it does not display that post. rather stay here `/blog/search/blogpost/my_article`

Comment: Problem solved  @WillemVanOnsem Thanks Bro.